# Command line equivalent of installing a package from ubuntu software center

Tags: package-management, software-installation, software-center

I just installed a package from Ubuntu software called gstreamer. Is there any general way that I can see what commands are run by the Ubuntu software center when installing a package so that we can regenerate them inside our scripts?

I am troubled finding the command line equivalent for these sort of installations.

I tried to grep a list of installed packages but it returns many packages with that keyword.

```
sudo apt list --installed | grep gstreamer
```

Does this mean that when we install gstreamer from Ubuntu software all these packages are installed automatically?

Is there a general solution for all packages? That is to see what commands are run behind the scene when we install a package using Ubuntu Software.

Comment: 1) There is not. 2) No, that's not what it means. 3) You seem to be assuming that *shell commands* are run behind the scenes, which is often not a valid assumption. You CAN monitor the chatter between Ubuntu Software and aptdaemon using the plain old `dbus-monitor` command...but it's machine talk, not trivial for humans to parse.

Comment: You could always look in logs (`/var/log/apt/history.log`) to see what *deb* packages were installed; but Ubuntu Software allows you to install different types of packages, so that log for example will show only *deb* packages.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I install applications in Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/307280/how-do-i-install-applications-in-ubuntu)

Comment: @user535733 I will try to have look at dbus-monitor. Thank you.

Comment: @guiverc I couldn't find anyhting useful in that history.log. Could you explain specifically?

Comment: @N0rbert No this is not what I exactly want. I need to now the name of the package in apt repository. The Ubuntu Software shows a commercial sort of name. Usually by that name we cannot install a package from command line because we would get package not found error!